# Book Id - sci-fi contemporary man becomes champion with big hammer?

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I am trying to find a novel I had at one time that was a story where dimensional shift or alien arrival resulted in champions emerging with special abilities - main character was male, pretty much a loser, but became powerful, especially with a war hammer and ended up in combat acting as a champion for earth….

Additional details:

-main character was full grown, loser in sense of not finding fulfilling role

-‘something’ happens that leads to a change in the universe that leads to a very small number of individuals developing abilities - strength, powers.  Main characters special weapon is either an axe or hammer.  Other champion characters that emerge have their own unique weapons/tactics/abilities

-this coincides/is caused by the appearance of ‘aliens’ who have a culture of challenge combat and are aware of the emergence of these champions, and who call out these champions - none of this is hidden BTW - the world is aware and media frenzy is part of this

-I remember at one point in the book, the main character succeeds in one of these challenges, and takes advantage of the publicity to party and celebrate (in vegas, perhaps).

-later in the book a secondary character emerges - female and Russian - who takes the responsibilities of the role more seriously as the champions are needed for earth to prevail since the military is not able to be effective against the strongest of the invaders.
-She can fly.

Update:

-not Donald Blake

-read within the last 5 years, believe published recently at that time

-not a litrpg style as there isn’t any leveling up of challenges for greater powers things…

Comment: You're sure it's not Donald Blake? Please take a look at our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if there might be anything else that comes to mind you can add to the question. Also, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when. Welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy.

Comment: @Jason Swan - In roughly which year or decade did you first read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: Was this a LitRPG story where people had, and were aware of, stats that they could improve and level up?